# Issue with creating a VIEW inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I needed to parse a JSON string from a column in a SQL Server 2008 R2 table, so I used 2 views and 3 tables and several stepped queries. Everything worked.

Now after populating several databases I need to allow for triggers to be placed on a specific table. Since only a stored procedure can be called from a trigger, I was converting everything into a stored procedure.

All went well except for a `CREATE VIEW` statement. I've wrapped that into EXEC but I'm still getting a syntax error regarding an unclosed quote. I've tried several different ways of enclosing keywords but nothing worked.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
EXEC ('If object_ID(''vw_BuildLookup01'',''V'') IS NOT NULL
            DROP VIEW vw_BuildLookup01;')
EXEC ('If object_ID(''vw_BuildLookup02'',''V'') IS NOT NULL
            DROP VIEW vw_BuildLookup02;')

EXEC ('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_BuildLookup01]
  AS
  SELECT DISTINCT t.tblKey, t.Name AS MetricTypesName, m.tblKey AS MetricKey, m.Name AS MetricName, 
  m.MetricLimitedValues, f.Value
  FROM  OccurrenceMetricFacts f
  INNER JOIN Metrics m ON f.MetricKey = m.tblKey 
  INNER JOIN MetricTypes t ON m.MetricTypeKey = t.tblKey 
  WHERE  m.MetricLimitedValues IS NOT NULL AND t.DeletedDate IS NULL AND f.Value IS NOT NULL
')

EXEC ('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_BuildLookup02]
  AS
  SELECT v.tblKey, v.MetricTypesName, v.MetricKey, v.MetricName,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(v.MetricLimitedValues, '"Name":"', ''),'","Value"', ''),'{', ''), '}',''),'[', ''), ']', '') AS MetricLimitedValues, v.Value
  FROM vw_BuildLookup01 v
  INNER JOIN MetricTypes t ON t.tblKey = v.tblKey
  WHERE t.DeletedDate IS NULL
')
```

The syntax error is on the line:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_BuildLookup02]
```

after the nested `REPLACE` commands the '"Name":"' has the dreaded red squiggly line underneath.

Comment: Sorry Dale, I don't post often. It's easier to read now after I added line breaks.

Comment: can you tell me how to get back to the editor?

Comment: Edited - hope it's easier to read now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You need to double up your single quotes because they look like the end of your dynamic SQL string to SQL Server.

Comment: Your `REPLACE` commands use single quotes inside of the larger string which is in single quotes.  You need to double up the single quotes, like `''{'', ''''`.

Comment: I doubled up on the single quotes the red squiggly went away but now I get: 
    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.
Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'Name'.

Comment: Try assigning your dynamic SQL string to a variable first, and then while debugging print the string instead of executing it, and then copy the printed string into a query window to check that you've built the correct string. Trying to debug dynamic SQL like you are doing is very difficult.

Comment: I've voted to close this question, because its no help to anyone else when its not clear what the issue is nor what the solution is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did with the PUBS database as an example.

Since it is doing EXEC, the entire sql is surrounded by an opening&closing single quote.

All interior quotes need to be a PAIR of SINGLE quotes.

```
EXEC ('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_BuildLookup02]
AS
SELECT
        [title_id]
       ,[title]
       ,REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        v.title, ''Name'', ''''),
         ''Value'', ''''),
         ''{'', ''''),
         ''}'', ''''),
         ''['', ''''),
         '']'', '''') 

        AS title2 

    FROM [pubs].[dbo].[titles] as v
    ');
```

Comment: Thank you donPablo!! I used your example, Dale thanks for all your help too